# Remove android notification "summary text" field

Tags: java, android, push-notification

[image]I am implementing an Android 7.0 notification.

But the problem is "summary text" field.
When I expand a grouped notification box, "summary text" field is remaining even though there's no contents.

So I want to remove this field.
What do I have to do, to remove this field. Below is the my notification code.

thanks.

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new 
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(topTitle);
bigTextStyle.bigText(title);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resIconID))
    .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightBlue))
    .setDeleteIntent(pendingDelIntent)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notiFlag, notificationBuilder.build());
PropertyManager.getInstance(this).setNotiCount(type, notiCount);
```

Comment: Do you inialize title in your code?

Comment: like String title="summary"

Comment: Correct me if wrong you do not want to show any summary text, all you want is show notification with Title?

Comment: I initialized the variables and I attached image file. As you can see, I just want to remove the red box area when I expand the group of notification.